# VB.Net check to determine if the object is null before calling the method

Tags: vb.net

I'm having the following problem, but can not identify the error, he points out that this is part of "Me.sr.Read (Me.srcBT, 0, CInt (Me.sr.Length))". Help.

```
Public Function getFile(ByVal srcFile As String) As String
    Dim result As String

    If File.Exists(srcFile) Then
        Using sr As FileStream = New FileStream(srcFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
            Dim srcBT(CInt(sr.Length) + 1) As Byte
            Me.sr.Read(Me.srcBT, 0, CInt(Me.sr.Length))
            Me.sr.Flush()
            Me.sr.Dispose()
            Me.sr.Close()
            result = Encoding.[Default].GetString(Me.srcBT)
            Return result
        End Using
    End If
    result = Nothing

    Return result
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Get rid of all those `Me.`; if it compiles that way, it would be using some other `sr` and some other `srcCBT` objects.  The ones you seem to need to use are all local.

Comment: You can replace most of your code with `IO.File.ReadAllText (srcFile)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have removed all "my", but the problem remains the same mistake.  check to determine if the object is null before calling the method    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of object

Comment: `the problem remains the same mistake` which of course you havent yet told us what that is or whether it is a compiler error or exception.  We dont live inside your computer

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, the error is as follows, as shown in the picture: http://imgur.com/a/7mi4p